# Google Chart - Refreshing chart on the same page

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a google chart graph on a page. What I want to get done is when a button is pressed, a different query is run and the chart refreshes. All my code is in one file called admin_store_view.php. I have tried the most obvious solution so calling the google chart script again on a successful AJAX but that didn't work.

```
$('#year_to_date').click(function(event){
    var page = 'admin_store_view.php';
    $.ajax({
        url : page,
        data : {'action' : 'year_to_date','store_id' : "<?php echo $store_id ?>"},
        type : 'post',
        success: function(result) {
             var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);
              var options = {

              vAxis: {title: 'Value (€)'},
              hAxis: {title: 'Audit Date'},
              legend:{position: 'top', maxLines:2},
              seriesType: 'bars',
              series: {
                  3: {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex:0},
                  4: {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex:1}
                  },
              vAxes: {
                1: {
                  title:'Gross Profit %',
                  textStyle: {color: 'green'}
                }
            }};

            var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        },
        error: function() {}
    });
});
```

Is there a different way to refresh the chart or do I have to move my PHP code to a separate file and reload the div with that data every time?